# CakeEmail non-object error in server

Tags: email, cakephp-2.0

I'm using CakePHP 2.0.6.

I'm trying to send a simple Email using CakeEmail.

In my controller I have:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
```

in my controller's action:

```
$email = new CakeEmail('default');
                $email->to('myemail@email.com')
                    ->template('template')
                    ->viewVars(array('var' => $this->Object->findById($this->Object->id)))
                    ->emailFormat('html')
                    ->subject('Subject')
                    ->send();
```

My default email config is:

```
public $clkei = array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtpout.secureserver.net',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'test@test.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'from' => array('test@test.com' => 'My Name'),
        'transport' => 'Smtp'
    );
```

However I keep getting:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function template() on a non-object in .../app/Controller/MyController.php on line 82
```

What I am missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

have it tried it without 'viewVars' and 'template'? just for testing try

```
$email = new CakeEmail('default');
            $email->to('myemail@email.com')
                ->template('template')
                ->viewVars(array('var' => $this->Object->findById($this->Object->id)))
                ->emailFormat('html')
                ->subject('Subject')
                ->send();
```